# To Trigger Bitbucket pipeline if any change happened in Azure DNS records

Tags: azure, ms-access, bitbucket, azure-dns

I am trying to trigger bitckut pipeline as soon as any change happend in Azure DNS record.

Can anyone suggest the solution and flow for same.

Regards,
Avbhi

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

*AFAIK, there will be no changes happen in Azure DNS record. When you trigger bitbucket pipeline*

Bitbucket pipeline are continuous integration and continuous delivery software if you are using bitbucket project inside bitbuket.org if you have a repository, you can enable bitbucket pipelines on the fly and whenever you push a code to this particular repository if you had a pipeline enabled ***your build gets triggered***

Comment: Actually we have certain conditions for Azure DNS service like if any records or updated/changed in DNS records in Azure platform then automatically bitbucket pipeline will get triggered and certain logics needs to be implemented on Azure DNS record ,so my challange is how to trigger pipeline if any change happend at DNS record label on Azure side so needing flow and algo for same which services/tools needs to be integrated to achieve this

Comment: you can use Custom pipelines. Custom pipelines block automatically trigger and to run manually you must have *write* access permission to the repository. [Reference](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/pipeline-triggers/) check this [Manage DNS records](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dns/dns-operations-recordsets-portal)